# python: assigning first class function to dictionary item

Tags: python, dictionary, first-class-functions

I have an existing dictionary and I want to add new element as a first-class function generated from a list.

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

```
agg_dict = {}
for x in attribute_list:
    agg_dict[x] = lambda x: ','.join(x)
```

I've tried using the list comprehensive and it doesn't work.

```
[agg_dict[x] = lambda x: ','.join(x) for x in attribute_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it should be `agg_dict[x]`, not `agg_dict['x']`. Also, you can just use a dict comprehension:

```py
agg_dict = {x: lambda arg: ','.join(arg) for x in attribute_list}
```

Comment: Thanks.. how will you do it if I am to add it to an existing dictionary?

Comment: If you're adding to an existing dictionary, a loop is the best approach. Readable code is always better than a one-liner.